# unable to make group clause in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to display the details of all managers and their respective employees.

I have one table "Employee" column (`EmployeeID`), and another column (`ManagerID`) which is foreign key to `employeeID`

Sample data:

`select * from tbl_employee`:

```
EmployeeID  Name    Salary  ManagerID   DepartmentID    HireDate
1         krishna   21000.00    4         1             2014-12-01 00:00:00.000
2         sanjay    31000.00    2         3             2014-12-02 00:00:00.000
3         Raju      12000.00    4         5             2014-12-03 00:00:00.000
4         kumar     27000.00    4         5             2014-12-04 00:00:00.000
5         renuka    55000.00    4         5             2014-12-05 00:00:00.000
6         prash     22000.00    6         1             2014-12-06 00:00:00.000
7         bhaskar   33000.00    4         3             2014-12-07 00:00:00.000
```

I need like this

```
      Manager_Name     Employee_Name    salary   ManagerID   Department HireDate
        kumar            krishna          21000.00  4              1      2014-12-01 
         kumar            Raju            12000.00  4              5      2014-12-03
```

I tried this:
`select managerid,name as manager_name from Employee group by ManagerID,name`:

```
managerid   manager_name
2          sanjay
4          bhaskar
4          krishna
4          kumar
4          Raju
4          renuka
6          prashant
```

Comment: seems like another case of "please do my homework" ... what have you tried so far?

Comment: select managerid,name as manager_name from Employee group by ManagerID,name

how to get manager name in place of managerid??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
SELECT m.Name as Manager_Name, e.Name as Employee_Name, e.Salary, e.ManagerID, e.Department, e.HireDate
 FROM tbl_employee e INNER JOIN tbl_employee m on e.managerId = m.EmployeeID     ORDER BY 1
```